# couchDB + codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, couchdb

Are there anyone who can help me out on how to connect a codeigniter-application with couchDB?

I have tried to find drivers or libraries, but without any success. What can I do to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, CodeIgniter just means PHP -- which means that any library that's written in PHP should do the trick, even if it's not specifically written for, or part of, CodeIgniter.

For a list of PHP libraries to communicate with CouchDb, you might want to take a look at this page of the official CouchDb's wiki : [Getting started with PHP](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_PHP)

Everything that's said there should work fine with CodeIgniter -- I don't see why it wouldn't.

Of course, you could also write your own communication layer -- shouldn't be that hard, as it only means a couple of REST requests...

... But I wouldn't do that, if I were you : using a well-known library means you'll be using code that's already been tested and fixed -- which means less risks of bugs, and less maintenance work for you.

Comment: Thanks Martin! You're the man! 
Do you know if there's any web interfaces available for couch that does what phpmyadmin does for mysql?

Comment: Found out Futon now. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you found a solution :-) *(I would not have been able to answer to that question ^^ )*

Answer (score 2):

I don't seem to be able to comment on answers (which I would do if I could; this is a bit much for answering a question made in a comment to an answer)

I think CouchDB comes with a web interface that you can access it (on ubuntu linux anyway) by pointing your browser to http://localhost:5984/_utils/

Comment: Thanks! Will check it out when I run CouchDB again in my test environment!